# Is this do-able in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: list, sql-server

I'm very new to `SharePoint` so please forgive me if its a dumb question.

I have a `SQL Server` database storing a set of manual tests and grouping information of the tests. I want to have a `list` to show all the test groups of manual tests, and when someone clicks on an item in the list, it pops up a dialog with all the manual tests within that group and allow the user to insert new results for the tests.

So I want it to be like this:
[image]
where Test Name and Description is queried from the database.

I want it so that when the user submits the form, the entries are inserted to the `SQL Server` database.

Does anyone know how to do this in `SharePoint`? I have tried `external lists`, `Surveys`, `Task lists` and haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

---

Edit: I'm using `SharePoint 2010`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to do this through REST services with SharePoint 2013 and create a new BCS connection to that database. REST exposes BCS with External Lists, and it's possible to write a new webpart page that facilitates the Tests, and displays the results whenever you click on the Test Name.

How to create an External List: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558778.aspx

Look into REST with BCS here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163227(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163227%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Can I do it with SharePoint 2010?